# How to communicate with Infinispan from outside JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan

I have the need to handle some messages with payload in the correct order and high performance in a cluster of JBoss EAP 6.1 nodes. 
The first idea was to use JMS to communicate these messages to JBoss, but that seems not to be easy at all (if you are interested in details, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355443/process-jms-messages-in-correct-order-and-with-good-performance) for a previous question regarding the scenario).

I had a look at infinispan, then, and have the feeling that i can handle all my requirements by using it. But what i didn't find out right now is:
How can i communicate with Infinispan from outside JBoss? Is it possible to send data to (or to put a key-value pair into) a particular cache from a client, maybe using hotrod, while this cache is accessible and configurable inside JBoss?

Comment: EAP does not provide a way to access Infinispan remotely. You'd need to take Infinispan Server and somehow deploy it manually on top of EAP. The simplest thing might some kind of REST call that then puts stuff in Infinispan. However, based on your requirements, I'd have imagined that JMS would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I will accept this statement as answer if you write it down once more as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EAP does not provide a way to access Infinispan remotely. You'd need to take Infinispan Server and somehow deploy it manually on top of EAP. The simplest thing might some kind of REST call that then puts stuff in Infinispan. However, based on your requirements, I'd have imagined that JMS would be a better choice.